# Finding the number of permutations for a three letter string with ABC and 123

Tags: visual-c++, permutation

I know from Algebra class that with ABC and 123 we can make 216 different permutations for a three letter string, right? (6 x 6 x 6) I'd like to create a console program in C++ that displays ever possible permutation for the example above. The thing is, how would I even begin trying to calculate them. Perhaps:

AAA
BAA
CAA
1BA
2BA
3CA
1AB
2BC
3CA

etc.

This is really hard to ask, but what would I have to do to ensure that I include every permutation? I know there are 216 but I don't know how to actually go about going through all of them.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!!!

Comment: two things, this sounds alot like homework... if so, tell us.  second,  show us some code--what you have you tried already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need a fixed-number strings, you can use `N` nested loops (three in your case).

```
string parts = "ABC123";
for (int i = 0 ; i != parts.size() ; i++)
    for (int j = 0 ; j != parts.size() ; j++)
        for (int k = 0 ; k != parts.size() ; k++)
            cout << parts[i] << parts[j] << parts[k] << endl;
```

If `N` is not fixed, you would need a more general recursive solution.

Comment: Thanks so much everybody!!! Some of this code is a little above my head because I'm still a beginner, but with some more research, I'm sure I can figure it out. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3):

It's really easy to do using recursion. Provided you have an array of all six elements, here's java code to do it. I am sure you can translate it to C++ easily.

```
void getAllCombinations(List<String> output, char[] chrs, String prefix, int length) {
    if (prefix.length() == length) {
        output.add(prefix);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0;i < chrs.length;i++) {
            getAllCombinations(output, chrs, prefix + chrs[i], length);
        }
    }
    return;
}
```

This is not perfect, but it should give you the general idea. 
Run it with parameters: empty list, array of available characters, empty string and length of desired strings.

Comment: Of course I would hide this function as private and rather expose an overload:

`List<String> getAllCombinations(char[] characters, int stringLength)`

which would then call this recursive one.

Comment: No, this is not homework. I'm just incorporating previous knowledge I learned from Algebra to calculate the number of permutations. I don't have any code yet because I don't even know how to accomplish my goal, which is why I asked this question.

Answer (score 0):

With three nested loops (one per character position) iterating over each of the 6 allowed characters it's hard *not* to see that every possibly combination has a corresponding set of loop indices, and that every set of legal loop indices has a corresponding 3 letter string. And that 1-1 correspondence between loop indices and strings is what you're looking for, I gather.